# VB.Net Chart created in code using WithEvents - Handler causes plot time to increase - why?

Tags: vb.net, events, charts

To start with I have a fairly unique situation in that I am dealing with large amounts of data  - multiple series of about 500,000 points each.  The typical plot time is about 1s which is perfectly adequate.

The chart is created 'WithEvents' in code and the plot time doesn't change.

However, when I add the sub with the handler for the click event ..

```
Private Sub Chart_Main_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
               ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart_Main.Click

    Dim y As Integer = Chart_Main.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X)
    'MsgBox(y)

End Sub
```

the plot time blows out to 3min. Even having no code in the sub, the result is the same. There is no reference to the click event in any of the code so I am at a loss as to why this is occurring.  I suspect it has something to do with the number of points being added but not knowing the cause is frustrating.

Is anyone able to explain what is going on?

Comment: Is your calculation running on the main thread? That is the thread where you create your interface and all the eventhandling takes place?

Comment: The calculation was running on the main thread however putting it a background worker thread didn't improve things.  I did run in to a problem with adding the chart object to a panel on the form containing the UI to the chart.  I've been able to get a listbox to update with a string in a threaded environment using InvokeRequired, but I just can't get my Panel to add a Chart.  Regardless, if I drop the chart update part of the code, the processing time of the main calculations is still 3min or so when I add the code for the click event above. Does that help narrow it down? Cheers for responding

Comment: Ok, try the following: Don't use the *Handles* keyword regarding your Chart_Main. Instead in your constructor initialize the handler via: *AddHandler Chart_Main.Click, AddressOf Chart_Main_Click* 
Then in your plot procedure before engaging the plot, use *RemoveHandler Char_Main.Click, AddressOf Chart_Main_Click* and when done with the plot you can add the handler again (as above)... Tell me if it works or you need an example.

Comment: Dumping half a million points in a chart is utterly pointless.  You don't have a monitor with half a million pixels across.

Comment: Well i must agree with Hans on that one... generally you should tidy up your graphical output BEFORE pumping it on the user interface. That way you wouldn't have problems with your event handler messing up your update time.

Comment: An extra zero slipped in to the original number.  Regardless, some people would say 50,000 was too much also.  I'm sorry if it isn't obvious to Hans but there are two reasons for it.  The points do produce a density effect which is necessary to see visually.  Second, there are faster ways to do the processing but the real process takes 15sec real time data running for a week before the process shutsdown.  I need to verify that the realtime calculations are accurate therefore the backtesting needs to use the same methods.

Comment: I am also working on algorithms to satisfactorily quantify the density effect changes but at this point in time a person still identifies the subtlety in the changes better than the algorithms I've been able to produce.

Comment: Well Hanse point suggests, that you create your chart in a non user interface object and achive the density effect there. Finally when you have a number of points that scale to your screen resolution you pump it onto the user interface. It'a a classic case of the Backend/Frontend issue. Your density effect belongs to the Backend of your Application. In comparison, a piece of 3D processing software does not pump all the textures there are in a scene on the the graphical device, but only the ones that are visible to the 'camera'

Comment: Hans comment was as unhelpful as his analysis.  The situation I am visualising has highly integrated calculations that identify dynamic characteristics that potentially go back to the beginning of each week.  The calculations I have are in a separate object and I can switch off the elements that draw to the chart (and avoid the performance problem).  Most of the time however the user is looking at the full set of data from the beginning of the week.  The object is performed on the main UI thread but moving it off doesn't provide any benefit to the program and did throw up some curly ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i don't know if the explanation in the comments was sufficient, so here some example code...

Also i wanted to try this myself!

Essencially, what you do is take control on when you want Windows to check the events.

For that, i suggested two wrappers on *AddHandler* and *RemoveHandler* that can safely be called from worker threads.

So, what you have to do, is:

- Initialize the Handler in the constructor
- Call RemoveClickHandler on your control, each time you want it to be left alone by the EventHandler
- But don't forget to reinitialize the handler afterwards via AddClickHandler

Also, your handler method should not have the 'Handles' keyword anymore...

```
Public Class MainForm
    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        m_pPictureClickHandler = New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf hndPictureClick)
        AddClickHandler(pbxFirst, m_pPictureClickHandler)
    End Sub

    ' Have a persistent local instance of the delegate (for convinience)
    Private m_pPictureClickHandler As MouseEventHandler

    Public Sub AddClickHandler(obj As Control, target As [Delegate])
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then 
            Me.Invoke(New Action(Of Control, [Delegate])(AddressOf AddClickHandler), obj, target) 
        Else
            AddHandler obj.MouseClick, target
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub RemoveClickHandler(obj As Control, target As [Delegate])
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then 
            Me.Invoke(New Action(Of Control, [Delegate])(AddressOf RemoveClickHandler), obj, target) 
        Else
            RemoveHandler obj.MouseClick, target
        End If
    End Sub

    ' Here your Plot is done
    Public Sub LockedPlot()
        RemoveClickHandler(pbxFirst, m_pPictureClickHandler)

        ' do something on your handler free control ...

        AddClickHandler(pbxFirst, m_pPictureClickHandler)
    End Sub

    ' This is your handler (note without a 'Handles' keyword)
    Private Sub hndPictureClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        ' do something with the click
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Yeah! You clicked at: {0}x{1}", e.X.ToString(),     e.Y.ToString()))
    End Sub
End Class
```

I suppose an even better design would be to create a child class of your chart that has an LPC style method called, say 'SafePlot', with folowing features:

- It accepts a pointer (delegate) to a procedure
- It will remove all the event handler before invoking the procedure
- Finally it would reinitialize the handlers on it's own after the job is done.
- It may require a collection to all handler refering to it's events.
- -> For that reason i'd let the class manage the handlers entiraly...

Alternativly you could put the 'SafePlot' idea in your main class. then you could manage the event handler there... but that is disputable

Well i can think of a few other ways to do this, but i'm cutting the brainstorming now!

If interested in one of these design solutions, give me a poke.

Comment: A big thanks for that!  I've got your code working on a basic version of my chart which I use for troubleshooting.  I'm starting on the main implementation now so I will know soon if it solves the problem of the processing time exploding or whether I've found another puzzle to unravel.

Comment: Happy to hear that. I'm also very interested in whether this solves your performance issues!

Comment: MrPaulch, I'm having a party in your honour!!  Works brilliantly.